# Modifying CSS Using Select Tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of options:

```
<select id="numOfcards">
    <option value="Select">Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

I also have flip-container that is, as a default, set at 33% width:

```
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    min-width: 400px;
    padding-right: 2px;
}
```

What I want to ultimately happen is this:

When the option 1 is selected, the width is 100%.
When the option 2 is selected, the width is 48%.
When the option 3 is selected, the width is 33%.
When the option 4 is selected, the width is 24%.
When the option 5 is selected, the width is 19%.

I don't need the full code for this, just to know if (A) this is possible without a backend language, and (B) the main concept behind it. I looked through google and stackoverflow and couldn't seem to find a question with these exact specifications. Preferably, I would want the answer as JS.

Thanks.

Comment: No backend language necessary. JavaScript can do this. Have you tried any?

Comment: Ok, that's good news. I tried to do onclick, but that did not work. If you have any other ideas? @putvande

Comment: Change the `value` attribute on each option to the corresponding percentage.  Add a JavaScript event handler to the select list, get the select list's `value` property (which will be the selected percentage) and use that to set the CSS.

Comment: What did the onclick do? What did it look like? Can you put that in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question. There are no practical ways to do this with pure-CSS, but it can be done quite easily with JavaScript. Each option should have data of the target width:
 i.e.
`<option value="1" data-width="100%">1</option>`

Then at the end of your page, add a `<script>`. Usually scripts are stored in separate `.js` files, so you add `<script src="main.js"></script>`. `<script>` `src` works just like `<img>` `src`, but you can also do **inline scripts** if you prefer not to store them in a separate file.

`main.js` will look like

```
var select = document.getElementById('numOfcards')
var containers = document.querySelectorAll('.flip-container')
select.onchange = function () {
  var selectedOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex]
  for(var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++)
    containers[i].style.width = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-width')
}
```

Comment: Is the for loop meant to have brackets?

Comment: @AlexeyAyzin brackets is optional if there is only one statement. But adding them is better habit.

Comment: Also onchange didn't seem to work. If you want to take a look at the product/source: https://secure.scheduleinterpreter.com/bestinterpreters/wip/dashboard/ada/Dashboard/dashboard.004.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in JavaScript, add an event listener to the `select` element that watches for the `change` event.

Whenever the change event is triggered, get the value and loop through all the `.flip-container` elements using `querySelectorAll`. Update the `.style.width` property on each according to the value of the select element.

Comment: might want to address the `min-width` directive as well as `width`

Comment: @TomerW good point. In JavaScript, it would be the `.style.minWidth` or `.style['min-width']` property.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it with a little jQuery:

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
    var selValue = parseInt(this.value, 10);
    switch (selValue) {
        case 1:
            $('.thing').css('width', '100%');
            break;
        case 2:
            $('.thing').css('width', '48%');
            break;
        case 3:
            $('.thing').css('width', '33%');
            break;
        case 4:
            $('.thing').css('width', '24%');
            break;
        case 5:
            $('.thing').css('width', '19%');
            break;
    }
});
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/ksr2p48j/

Comment: Do you have an answer without jQuery? OP didn't tag it.